# Regex of base classes

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a hexadecimal calculator but I have a problem with the `regex`.

Basically, I want the string to only accept `0-9`, `A-E`, and special characters `+-*_`

My code keeps returning false no matter how I change the regex, and the adding the asterisk is giving me a `PatternSyntaxException` error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "1A_16+2B_16-3C_16*4D_16";

    String regex = "[0-9A-E+-_]";

    System.out.println(input.matches(regex));

}
```

Also whenever I add the `*` as part of the regex it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 9
[0-9A-E+-*_]+
         ^
```

Comment: Are you sure your actual code doesn't have `regex.matches(input)`? http://ideone.com/YtmyTY

Comment: `F` is a valid hexadecimal character too. Still, what you really need is to use a lexer and a parser.  See `lex` and `yacc` in traditional UNIX, or GNU `flex` and `bison` in Linux and ports.  Don't you want `/` instead of `_`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match more than one character with your regex. As it currently stands you only match one character.

To match one or more characters add a `+` to the end of the regex

```
[0-9A-E+-_]+
```

Also to match a `*` just add a star in the brackets so the final regex would be

```
[0-9A-E+\\-_*]+
```

You need to escape the `-` otherwise the regex thinks you want to accept all character between `+` and `_` which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks! That fixes it for the most part. But I am still receiving a PatternSyntaxException error when I add * as part of the regex. What is happening here?

Comment: I don't get that exception when I run it. Can you create a small example that shows that?

Comment: @MarcoLau You might need to escape the `*` within the brackets: `\\*`

Comment: @MarcoLau you need to escape `-` `[0-9A-E+\\-*_]+` otherwise regex will try to create range from `+` till `*` but in [Unicode table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) `*` is before `+` so range is wrong. Other option is to put `-` at start of end of your character class, `[-...` or `...-]` but that solution is not guaranteed to be working in other regex engines beside Java.

Comment: @MarcoLau weird... Adding it to the end doesn't cause the exception and Doing what vulcan says doesn't help as in the escaping just puts a slash in the pattern. Pshemo is correct. Escape the `-`

Comment: Put the hyphen at the end; there's no way to make that part of a range, so regex engines don't do that.  Escaping rules are much different for character classes than for the rest of regular expressions.  So, try `[0-9A-Fa-f+*_-]+`.

Comment: @Pshemo I got it working! However, I want to know whether it's recommended to escape the hyphen or put it at the end? Or is this just about preference?

Comment: @MarcoLau I prefer `\\-` since it is easier to maintain later, especially for someone that will try to improve my code by adding new characters at the end of `[..-]` without knowing about special meaning of `-` (real story :).

Answer (score 1):

You regex is OK there should be no exceptions, just add `+` at the end of regex which means one or more characters like those in brackets, and it seems you wanted `*` as well

```
"[0-9A-E+-_]+"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isValidCode (String code) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[fFtTvV\\-~^<>()]+"); //a-zA-Z
    Matcher m = p.matcher(code);
    return m.matches();
}
```